# Mixing unicode and str in python 2.X ... problems?

Tags: python, email

```
mystr = 'aaaa'
myvar = u'My string %s' % str(mystr)
```

Can this be a problem in the future? I'm messing up woth some in-house code that uses email modules in Python and found some code like this. `mystr` will always have only ascii characters since it comes from a list with pre defined ascii only characters.

I didn't write the code, and having `str(mystr)` or `mystr` doesn't change the matter of the question.

Doing the first snippet I'm going to have a safe unicode object, or do **I have to** do

```
mystr = u'aaaa'
myvar = u'My string %s' % mystr
```

or

```
mystr = 'aaaa'
myvar = u'My string %s' % unicode(mystr)
```

?

(I know this is not the correct way of doing, I know I should handle the exceptions, I'm asking here only if the first snippet returns a valid unicode object, or if Python mess up with it's internals or something when doing it.)

Comment: 2 upvotes? 2 downvotes would be appropriate

Comment: @Blackmoon: I have added more info in the question. `mystr` will always have only ascii characters.

Comment: What problems do you foresee?

Comment: "mystr will always have only ascii characters." is not an acceptable assuption for writing valid code.

Comment: @David Heffernan: None. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Well, I can't begin to guess what you will do to this code in the future, so I've no idea whether or not you will break it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting actual unicode symbols in the strings (like umlauts or cyrillic) and watch hell breaking lose. :)

```
s = 'свят' # world
v = u'здравей %s' % s # hello %s 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The problem is that you will most likely code your application and on a bright shiny day some Russian or German will write her name and will suddenly get an `Internal Server Error` for having a non-ascii symbol in her name.

---

> I know... I'm asking about the situation in my example, using ascii only in

No, there will be no problem. And IMHO this is a fault in Python, because this is bug, waiting to bite. This should have been a fatal error, but because of historical reasons, I guess, it isn't.

Comment: I know... I'm asking about the situation in my example, using ascii only in `mystr`.

Comment: using only ASCII is a stupid assumption. There will be always data being non-ascii and your application will burp and you will come back to SO and start with crying.

Comment: Having ASCII only data is not an excuse for writing bad code.

Comment: @Blackmoon: Guys, please, I just want to know which exactly problems this is going to have. I don't want to read "don't assume it will always be ascii" because it will. `mystr` always comes from a pre-define list with only ascii characters.

Comment: So why the hell do you need to call str() here?

Comment: @Blackmoon: This is just the code I came across. I didn't wrote it. Removing it or not, the question remains. This is not the point.

Comment: it's absolutely the point - writing clean is the question. Code working only under some evil assumptions like "ascii-only" is *broken* code.

Comment: It's not a problem in Python 3, though (not this specific issue, at least). `s = 'свят';v = 'здравей %s' % s;print(v)` results in "дравей свят".

Comment: @JAB, one of the biggest changes in Python 3 was to make all strings Unicode. Not very helpful for someone still using Python 2.x, unless they're willing to convert.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Correct. I've edited my question, is now only about Python 2.X.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the regular 8-bit string contains only ASCII characters, you're fine. This can be done to save processing time and / or memory space if you really only need ASCII.

Can it be a problem in the future? Yes, if you're taking input possibly in a non-ASCII character set and saving it in a string. It's also just generally a good idea to be consistent -- don't use strings as storage for text anywhere if you need Unicode widely, unless there is a good reason otherwise.